# LibGdx 2 half screen "buttons"

Tags: java, android, libgdx

(Android) So I'm new to LibGdx and I'm trying to code this chrome dino mini game.. I want to make action 1 when the user touch the left hand side of the screen and make action 2 when he touch the right hand side of the screen, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the side being touched by using the following code somewhere inside your game loop:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    if (Gdx.input.getX() > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2){
        //touched right
    } else {
        //touchde left
    }
}
```